# Regex to match valid lines only

Tags: regex, perl

I have written a script that summarises very long log files.  The one little problem I have is that the logs are prone to having corrupt entries and as such my summary sometimes contains some of these bad lines.
My script produces an intermediate temporary file which I need to pick out only the valid lines from it.

The following lines are valid and I need to match lines such as these:

```
21/05/14   09:17   134U      0993    EUser_Message 01    
21/05/14   11:07   134UD     0994    User_Message B02   
21/05/14   11:47   134P      0995    User_Message UOD1   
21/05/14   12:41   134B18    0996    User_Message UOD2   
21/05/14   14:00   134B      0997    User_Message T02   
21/05/14   14:22   134NV     0998    User_Message D02   
21/05/14   15:25   121U      0999    EUser_Message 03   
21/05/14   16:38   121UD     1000    EUser_Message 04   
22/05/14   07:39   134TP     1001    EUser_Message 08   
22/05/14   09:55   134P      1002    EUser_Message 13  
22/05/14   10:46   134B      1003    EUser_Message 14  
22/05/14   12:00   134NonVac 1004    User_Message UOD3
```

These are valid because they contain the string *"User_Message"* and they are formed quite specifically in a certain way:

> (2 digits)(forward slash)(2 digits)(forward slash)(2 digits)(3 spaces)(2 digits)(colon)(2 digits)(3 spaces)(4 to 9 letters or numbers)(1 to 6 spaces)(4 digits)(4 spaces)("User_Message string")(0 or 1 space)(new line)

Examples of entries that need to be ignored would be:

```
User_Message UOD1     
19/08/14   11:46   1388    EUser_Message 01    
03/07/13   0645    03/07/13   0646    03/07/13   0647    03/07/13   15:36   134U    0648      
0862    17/04/14   0866    17/04/14   0867    17/04/14   0868    17/04/14  
17/04/14   10:04   134TP   0869    EUser_Message 01      
21/05/14   14:02   134B    0982    
0983    22/05/14   22/05/14   12:48   134U    0984    User_Message UOD1  
1015    03/06/14   
11/07/13   08:12   134B    0011    
11/07/13   12:39   134B    0012   
11/07/13   13:53   134B    0013    
12/07/13   08:01   134P    0014    
12/07/13   08:29   134B    0015
```

My section of code that's attempting to match valid lines is:

```
if ($line =~ /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s{3}\d{2}:d{2}\s{3}\d{4}\s{4}.*\n/) {
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how to correctly build a regex that would match only the valid lines of text shown above.

Comment: try with help of sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) so you can look is it working or not with every added character

Comment: most examples of valid input have more that 1 space on the end of line, so are these line valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't single-regex this - regular expressions are powerful, but they're ... well, rather prone to being unintelligible and vulnerable to edge cases.

I would approach this by first `split`ing your line into fields, and validating each of them. One particularly useful trick is you can use `eval` and `Time::Piece->strptime` to validate a date quite effectively.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my ( $date, $time, $somecode, $othercode, $msgtype, $msgcode ) = split;

   if ( $date =~ m,^\d+/\d+/\d+$, 
   and $time =~ m,^\d+:\d+$, 
   and eval { Time::Piece->strptime("$date $time", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M") } ) {
       print "Date is ok\n";
   }
   else { print "$date $time is invalid\n"; next; }

   if ( $somecode =~ m/^\w+\d+$/ ) {  
       print "somecode is ok\n";
   }
   else {
       print "Error with somecode $somecode\n";
   }

   if ( $othercode =~ m,^\d{4}$, ) {
       print "othercode is ok\n";
   }
   else { 
        print "Error with $othercode \n";
        next;
   }

   if ( $msgtype =~ m/User_Message/ 
   and $msgcode =~ m/\w+/ ) {
       print "$msgtype $msgcode ok\n";
   }
   else {
       print "Error with $msgtype $msgcode\n"; 
       next;
   }

   print "Line: $. is ok\n$_";
}

__DATA__
21/05/14   09:17   134U      0993    EUser_Message 01    
21/05/14   11:07   134UD     0994    User_Message B02   
21/05/14   11:47   134P      0995    User_Message UOD1   
21/05/14   12:41   134B18    0996    User_Message UOD2   
21/05/14   14:00   134B      0997    User_Message T02   
21/05/14   14:22   134NV     0998    User_Message D02   
21/05/14   15:25   121U      0999    EUser_Message 03   
21/05/14   16:38   121UD     1000    EUser_Message 04   
22/05/14   07:39   134TP     1001    EUser_Message 08   
22/05/14   09:55   134P      1002    EUser_Message 13  
22/05/14   10:46   134B      1003    EUser_Message 14  
22/05/14   12:00   134NonVac 1004    User_Message UOD3
User_Message UOD1     
19/08/14   11:46   1388    EUser_Message 01    
03/07/13   0645    03/07/13   0646    03/07/13   0647    03/07/13   15:36   134U    0648      
0862    17/04/14   0866    17/04/14   0867    17/04/14   0868    17/04/14  
17/04/14   10:04   134TP   0869    EUser_Message 01      
21/05/14   14:02   134B    0982    
0983    22/05/14   22/05/14   12:48   134U    0984    User_Message UOD1  
1015    03/06/14   
11/07/13   08:12   134B    0011    
11/07/13   12:39   134B    0012   
11/07/13   13:53   134B    0013    
12/07/13   08:01   134P    0014    
12/07/13   08:29   134B    0015
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take the same approach as [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%c3%9cn%c3%bcr) and split the data into fields first before verifying each one of them

It looks very much like your data has fixed-width fields, which are conveniently parsed using [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) with multiple `An` templates, where `n` is the number of characters ocupied by the field. This template extracts the given number of characters and trims any trailing whitespace, so will correctly process your data if given the size of each column from the start of one field to the start of the next

This program keeps a separate array `@validation` of regex patterns that will match only valid contents of the corresponding fields. Each record is first split into fields using an appropriate `unpack` pattern (the trailing `A*` simply soaks up *everything else*). It is then verified by first assuming validity with `$valid = 1` and then comparing each field with its corresponding validation pattern; the loop terminates either when all fields have been validated or an invalid field has been found

I have used all of the data you provide in your question: the twelve valid lines followed by the thirteen invalid ones. The output correctly shows just the initial twelve lines

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.14;    # For regex /a modifier
use re '/a';  # Regex patterns match only ASCII characters

my $template = 'A11 A8 A10 A8 A*';

my @validation = (
    qr{^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d$},
    qr{^\d\d:\d\d$},
    qr{^[0-9A-Z]+$}i,
    qr{^\d+$},
    qr{^E?User_Message\s+\w+$},
);

my ($total, $n) = (0, 0);

while ( <DATA> ) {

    ++$total;

    my @fields = unpack $template, $_;

    my $valid = 1;
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#fields ) {
        $valid = $fields[$i] =~ $validation[$i];
        last if not $valid;
    }

    if ( $valid ) {
        ++$n;
        print;
    }
}


print "\n$n valid records of $total\n";

__DATA__
21/05/14   09:17   134U      0993    EUser_Message 01
21/05/14   11:07   134UD     0994    User_Message B02
21/05/14   11:47   134P      0995    User_Message UOD1
21/05/14   12:41   134B18    0996    User_Message UOD2
21/05/14   14:00   134B      0997    User_Message T02
21/05/14   14:22   134NV     0998    User_Message D02
21/05/14   15:25   121U      0999    EUser_Message 03
21/05/14   16:38   121UD     1000    EUser_Message 04
22/05/14   07:39   134TP     1001    EUser_Message 08
22/05/14   09:55   134P      1002    EUser_Message 13
22/05/14   10:46   134B      1003    EUser_Message 14
22/05/14   12:00   134NonVac 1004    User_Message UOD3
User_Message UOD1
19/08/14   11:46   1388    EUser_Message 01
03/07/13   0645    03/07/13   0646    03/07/13   0647    03/07/13   15:36   134U    0648
0862    17/04/14   0866    17/04/14   0867    17/04/14   0868    17/04/14
17/04/14   10:04   134TP   0869    EUser_Message 01
21/05/14   14:02   134B    0982
0983    22/05/14   22/05/14   12:48   134U    0984    User_Message UOD1
1015    03/06/14
11/07/13   08:12   134B    0011
11/07/13   12:39   134B    0012
11/07/13   13:53   134B    0013
12/07/13   08:01   134P    0014
12/07/13   08:29   134B    0015
```

### output

```
21/05/14   09:17   134U      0993    EUser_Message 01
21/05/14   11:07   134UD     0994    User_Message B02
21/05/14   11:47   134P      0995    User_Message UOD1
21/05/14   12:41   134B18    0996    User_Message UOD2
21/05/14   14:00   134B      0997    User_Message T02
21/05/14   14:22   134NV     0998    User_Message D02
21/05/14   15:25   121U      0999    EUser_Message 03
21/05/14   16:38   121UD     1000    EUser_Message 04
22/05/14   07:39   134TP     1001    EUser_Message 08
22/05/14   09:55   134P      1002    EUser_Message 13
22/05/14   10:46   134B      1003    EUser_Message 14
22/05/14   12:00   134NonVac 1004    User_Message UOD3

12 valid records of 25
```

---

#### Update

Note that, if you're able and willing to install the [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) and [`Regexp::Common::time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time) modules, then you can make the patterns for the date and time fields even more selective like this

```
my @validation = (
    qr{^$RE{time}{tf}{ -pat => 'd/m/yy' }$},
    qr{^$RE{time}{tf}{ -pat => 'h:m' }$},
    qr{^[0-9A-Z]+$}i,
    qr{^\d+$},
    qr{^E?User_Message\s+\w+$},
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets translate this exactly:

> (2 digits)(forward slash)(2 digits)(forward slash)(2 digits)(3 spaces)(2 digits)(colon)(2 digits)(3 spaces)(4 to 9 letters or numbers)(1 to 6 spaces)(4 digits)(4 spaces)("User_Message string")(0 or 1 space)(new line)

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} {3}\d{2}:\d{2} {3}\w{4,9} {1,6}\d{4} {4}E?User_Message ?/
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/cP2dU4/1)

The only line that it matches right now and you said you didn't want to is

```
17/04/14   10:04   134TP   0869    EUser_Message 01
```

which I can't see why shouldn't match by the rules you described.

I am guessing that it was because you wanted the *(4 to 9 letters or numbers)* and *(1 to 6 spaces)* to always add up to *10* characters. We can ensure this with a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - `(?=.{10}\b\d)`

Giving us the final:

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} {3}\d{2}:\d{2} {3}(?=.{10}\b\d)\w{4,9} {1,6}\d{4} {4}E?User_Message ?/
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/cP2dU4/2)

Comment: You should add an end_of_line anchor.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, the start anchor is good enough. In order to add `$` I would also need to add the final part (the one after `User_Message`), which OP hasn't yet defined a pattern for.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I'm looking for, but in my code it's not matching anything.  If I take off the User_Message bit it matches even bad lines.

Comment: @ndn: if you read carefully the description you can see at the end `(0 or 1 space)(new line)`.

Comment: @PeteG: instead of trying to count the exact number of spaces, use `\h+` or `[ \t]+` to figure them.

Comment: @PeteG, you can see it working [here](https://code.hackerearth.com/84dd13i). There must be a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, if you read carefully, you will see that I have implemented the *User Message* part as only `User_Message` instead of `User_Message B02`.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice the description was wrong.

Comment: Still struggling.  I hope this [link](https://code.hackerearth.com/e0a594U?key=9fdc1a419c9d8b653a28d8f81e5e0e18) helps?

Comment: @PeteG, [here](https://code.hackerearth.com/e0a594U) I commented the file reading related part of your code. You can see that it is still working. Therefore, I guess there is a problem with the contents of your file.

Comment: @PeteG, actually I saw that in the code you gave you showed an example of good line where the sum of (4 to 9 letters or numbers) and (1 to 6 spaces) wasn't 10 characters. You could try the first version of the regex instead if that is the case.

Comment: Done!  I was having issues with the number of spaces just as @ndn pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The exact numbers of spaces between columns may or may not be relevant. If this is supposed to be fixed-width field data, then you should use [unpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#unpack-TEMPLATE-EXPR).

A valid log line must have six (or maybe five) fields consisting of:

1. A date
2. A time
3. Some kind of identifier
4. Another identifier
5. Message identifier
6. Another identifier

With unpack, you can extract the fields using `unpack 'A11 A9 A11 A9 A20', $line`. You can still validate those fields individually.

Instead of messing around with *one regex pattern to rule them all*, you should extract each field and validate it separately.

Here is a self-contained example. It assumes space-separated data for field extraction, but it would work almost the same way for fixed width field data just by replacing `split` with `unpack` and figuring out the correct number and names of the fields.

I have left a few validators for you to fill in given uncertainties in my understanding of your problem description.

There are many more ways to do this kind of thing such as [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate) as well as just building a large regex pattern from constituent pieces. But, it seems to me you have space-separated columns, and sometimes the cognitive burden of six separate small checks is lighter than one regex.

Also, this make it easier to add further code to check if the date really is a valid date, if it falls in certain ranges etc without crowding out the actual flow of the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package My::LogEntry;

use Carp qw( croak );
use Moo;

my @fields = qw( date time field3 field4 msg_type field6 );
has $_ => (is => 'ro', trigger => 1) for @fields;

sub _trigger_date {
    my $self = shift;
    my $date = shift;
    unless ($date =~ m{\A [0-9]{2} / [0-9]{2} / [0-9]{2} \z}x) {
        croak "Invalid date '$date'";
    }
    return;
}

sub _trigger_time {
    my $self = shift;
    my $time = shift;
    unless ($time =~ m{\A [0-9]{2} : [0-9]{2} \z}x) {
        croak "Invalid time '$time'";
    }
    return;
}

sub _trigger_field3 {}

sub _trigger_field4 {}

sub _trigger_msg_type {
    my $self = shift;
    my $msg_type = shift;
    unless ($msg_type =~ m{ \A E? User_Message \z }x) {
        croak "Invalid message type '$msg_type'";
    }
    return;
}

sub _trigger_field6 {}

sub do_something { }

sub BUILDARGS {
    my $class = shift;
    unless (@fields == @_) {
        croak sprintf(
            '%s constructor called with %d args (%s), need %d',
            $class,
            scalar @_,
            join(',', @_),
            scalar @fields
        );
    }
    my $ret = {
        map +( $fields[$_] => $_[$_] ), 0 .. $#_
    };
}

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @entry = split ' ', $line;
    my $entry;
    eval { $entry = My::LogEntry->new(@entry) };
    if ( $entry ) {
       $entry->do_something;
    }
    else {
       warn "$.: $@";
    }
}

__DATA__
21/05/14   09:17   134U      0993    EUser_Message 01
21/05/14   11:07   134UD     0994    User_Message B02
21/05/14   11:47   134P      0995    User_Message UOD1
21/05/14   12:41   134B18    0996    User_Message UOD2
21/05/14   14:00   134B      0997    User_Message T02
21/05/14   14:22   134NV     0998    User_Message D02
21/05/14   15:25   121U      0999    EUser_Message 03
21/05/14   16:38   121UD     1000    EUser_Message 04
22/05/14   07:39   134TP     1001    EUser_Message 08
22/05/14   09:55   134P      1002    EUser_Message 13
22/05/14   10:46   134B      1003    EUser_Message 14
22/05/14   12:00   134NonVac 1004    User_Message UOD3
User_Message UOD1
19/08/14   11:46   1388    EUser_Message 01
03/07/13   0645    03/07/13   0646    03/07/13   0647    03/07/13   15:36   134U    0648
0862    17/04/14   0866    17/04/14   0867    17/04/14   0868    17/04/14
17/04/14   10:04   134TP   0869    EUser_Message 01
21/05/14   14:02   134B    0982
0983    22/05/14   22/05/14   12:48   134U    0984    User_Message UOD1
1015    03/06/14
11/07/13   08:12   134B    0011
11/07/13   12:39   134B    0012
11/07/13   13:53   134B    0013
12/07/13   08:01   134P    0014
12/07/13   08:29   134B    0015
```

Comment: *"The exact numbers of spaces between columns is not relevant"* This looks like it may be fixed-width fields, and since we don't know how the data is being corrupted, incorrect spacing of the fields may reflect problems in the non-space data